# What is the best equivalent of a MATLAB "cell of structures" in python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a code in MATLAB that I'm converting in python. The following is the body of the code

```
load("A.mat")
nobj= 2
pop=cell(200,1);
for i=1:200
   pop{i,1}.subsystem= A(i,:);
   pop{i,1}.objectives=zeros(1,nobj);
end
```

This code creates a MATLAB cell of 200 structures and each structure contains two fields - 1 field is the (array) row from a loaded matrix 'A' and the other field is nobj which is another array. what is the python equivalent of this? Thanks

Comment: A [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of [`dicts`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: You maybe don't care, but that MATLAB code is not efficient at all. You should be using a struct array there. `pop=[]` and then `pop(i).subsystem=...` etc.

Comment: @Cris I think `pop = struct([])` is the "clear" way to initialise a structure array